# How to use Jquery to select a specific column to set no copy/paste.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table with only table ID, no unique class associated with any column or row or cell.

```
  <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Person ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>123456</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I wrote following code snippet to make client not be able to copy/paste text in "First Name" column. But for some reason, this code make the whole table not to be able to copy/paste.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var ths = tbl.getElementsByTagName('th');
    var trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var column = [];

    var id;

    for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++)
    {
        if (ths[i].innerHTML.indexOf('First Name') >= 0)
        {
            id = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (var t = 0; t < trs.length; t++)
    {
        column.push(trs[t].children[id]);
    }

    $(column).bind('copy paste cut drag drop contextmenu', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code will not run in your example since there is no th elements.

Comment: You have used td for headingand in jQuery you are checking for th.Just make tds of first <tr> <th> and you will get your output

Comment: Added an answer which should solve your problem - If it does, mark it as correct answer pls!

Answer (score 0):

So this script should solve your problem:

```js
$('#table tr').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).on('copy paste cut drag drop contextmenu','td:first', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Person ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>123456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>654321</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: I still don't get it ... why *paste* ??

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the threadstarter. It works anyway so you can delete the "paste"...

Comment: It didn't work on me, may you include the Javascript in the code nippet so that I can run to test on StackOverFlow?